# WSUS server filter and approved required updates

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update

I am trying to write a PowerShell script for filtering the updates which will contain only 2008 R2 and ignore the declined one and then approve the filtered result. I was able to get the filtered list but was unable to get the approve. Is there a method to approve it.

```
$WsusServerAdminProxy = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::GetUpdateServer()

$test = $WsusServerAdminProxy.GetUpdates() | Where-Object {$_.Title -match “Windows server 2008 R2| Windows server 2012 R2 | Windows server 2012” -and -not $_.IsDeclined}
```

Comment: Is your script for Server 2008 or 2012 or should it work on both? Because Server 2012 introduced a WSUS-module to PowerShell., which makes scripting a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply to this:

```
$update.IsApproved = $true
```

If you get one of those updates and pipe it into `Get-Member` ($update | Get-Member) you see what options you have. One if it is `IsApproved    Property    bool IsApproved {get;set;}`

Here are some more properties you can use:

```
IsApproved                                 Property   bool IsApproved {get;set;}
IsBeta                                     Property   bool IsBeta {get;set;}
IsDeclined                                 Property   bool IsDeclined {get;set;}
IsEditable                                 Property   bool IsEditable {get;set;}
IsLatestRevision                           Property   bool IsLatestRevision {get;set;}
IsSuperseded                               Property   bool IsSuperseded {get;set;}
```

Comment: I can see the property IsApproved when I pipe the Get-Member to my object However when I try to set it to true using $test.IsApproved = $true it gives an error as below: "Property 'IsApproved' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable."